# how to send full html+images enabled mail to subscribers

Tags: email, c#-4.0, gmail, asp.net-4.0

i have just created one newsletter application that send html enabled and image embedded mail to large no of subscribers. i have some small problem with received mail to my gmail account. can't get full html mail to read. here is my code :

```
private static void SendEmail(string fromName, string fromEmailAddress, string emailpassword, string smtphost, int smtpport, bool enableSSL, string toEmailAddress, string subject, string plainText, List<string> file_names, int templateID, bool IsUnsubscriptionLink, SmtpClient client)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        if (fromName != null)
            msg.From = new MailAddress(fromName + " <" + fromEmailAddress + ">");
        else
            msg.From = new MailAddress(fromEmailAddress);
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmailAddress));
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        client.Host = smtphost;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential basicauthenticationinfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromEmailAddress, emailpassword);
        client.Port = smtpport;
        client.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = basicauthenticationinfo;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        msg.Subject = subject;
        string rbody = ConvertAllString(plainText, templateID);
        string fbody = rbody.Replace("\"", "'");
        if (fbody.Contains("src='cid:"))
        {
            var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msg.Body, null, "text/html");
            do
            {
                int src = fbody.IndexOf("src='cid:");
                if (src != -1)
                {
                    fbody = fbody.Remove(0, src + 9);
                    var dot = Regex.Match(fbody, @"\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)");
                    if (dot.Success)
                    {
                        int comma = fbody.IndexOf("'");
                        if (comma != -1)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fbody.Substring(0, comma)))
                            {
                                string imageSource = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "EmailImages\\", fbody.Substring(0, comma));
                                var leftImageLink = (dynamic)null;
                                switch (Path.GetExtension(imageSource).ToLower())
                                {
                                    case ".jpg":
                                        leftImageLink = new LinkedResource(imageSource, "image/jpg")
                                        {
                                            ContentId = fbody.Substring(0, comma),
                                            TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64
                                        };
                                        break;
                                    case ".jpeg":
                                        leftImageLink = new LinkedResource(imageSource, "image/jpeg")
                                        {
                                            ContentId = fbody.Substring(0, comma),
                                            TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64
                                        };
                                        break;
                                    case ".gif":
                                        leftImageLink = new LinkedResource(imageSource, "image/gif")
                                        {
                                            ContentId = fbody.Substring(0, comma),
                                            TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64
                                        };
                                        break;
                                    case ".png":
                                        leftImageLink = new LinkedResource(imageSource, "image/png")
                                        {
                                            ContentId = fbody.Substring(0, comma),
                                            TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64
                                        };
                                        break;
                                }
                                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(leftImageLink);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            while (fbody.Contains("src='cid:"));
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
        }
        if (templateID > 0)
        {
            //do smething else
        }
        if (file_names.Count > 0)
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < file_names.Count; i++)
                {
                    Attachment mailAttachment = new Attachment(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "EmailFiles/" + file_names[i].ToString()));
                    msg.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);
                }
            }
        }
        if (IsUnsubscriptionLink.Equals(1))
        {
            string pathToApp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EASYMAIL_PathToApplication"];
            string unsubscribeText = "<br/>\r\n\r\n---------------------------\r\n<br/>" +
                                     "To unsubscribe, please click this link:\r\n" +
                                     pathToApp + "Unsubscribe.aspx";
            msg.Body = plainText + unsubscribeText;
        }
        else
        {
            msg.Body = plainText + string.Empty;
        }
        client.Send(msg);
    }
```

here is my gmail output for getting mail to my account :

[image]

how ever this my original mail generated from gmail is :

[image]

how ever i can't see full email rich text. guys please help me what's going wrong here...

Comment: If you use images as attachments, all mail clients will see those as attachments, you cannot avoid this behaviour. If your intent is to use the images like newsletter, your best option is to host the images in a webserver with public access, and just use them in the template with the html <img src="http:// yourserver /image.jpg"/> this is what newsletter services (e.g. Mailchimp) actually do.

Comment: this algorithem is to do with attachments to emails....

Answer (score 1):

few things about creating mail templates.

- Always thinks in terms of table . your whole HTML is a table structure.
- To send images as attachments , use cid.

Attached sample HTML code to show what i mean.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Sample*emphasized text*</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="left" valign="top">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                        <div >
                            <table>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style=" text-align: right;min-width:60px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                        <font>line1
                                            :</font>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <font>
                                            lin2</font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="vertical-align: top;">
                                    <td style=" text-align: right;min-width:70px;" align="left" valign="top">
                                        <font>line3
                                            :</font>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="hyphens: auto" align="left" valign="top">
                                        <font>
                                            how to show atachements inplace </font>
                                        <div style="overflow: scroll">
                                            <img src="cid:va" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" height="10" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body> </html>
```

- HTML max size can be exactly 102KB.

example

```
var v = []
    v.push({filename: "file_name_to_show", path: 'path_to_image', cid:'va'});

var mail = {
        from: "from_id",
        to: "to_id",
        subject: "adasda",
        text: "sample format",
        html: 'attach html object',
        attachments: v

    };
```

in HTML just define image source as

```html
<img src="cid:va">
```